# Angular socket fails with 400 bad request

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

Its an angular app (angular 1.X) that tries to connect to node-app.
It hasn't been easy to set up (primarly the frontend) so I ended up with having this on frontend (in bower.json):

```
"socket.io-client": "^0.7.10",
"angular-socket-io": "^0.7.0"
```

and this on backend (in package.json):

```
"socket.io": "^1.7.3",
```

So client has version less than 1.X while server has version bigger than 1.X.

When I try to connect I get

```
Bad request (HTTP 400)
```

while trying to go to

```
http://localhost/socket.io/1/
```

I only entered this in my socketFactory on frontend:

```
io.connect('http://localhost/', {'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']});
```

I guess the problem is the different versions on front and back? Must they be exactly the same or it is enough being both 0.X och 1.X?
Moreover, isn't there a workaround? Im quite sure that upgrading frontend to 1.X will cause other problems (that were lost when I downgraded to less than 1.X)

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to go to http://localhost/socket.io/1/ you're doing HTTP method GET request. It's different than connection via sockets. 
So it's normal that it returns bad request response when you opening http://localhost/socket.io/1/ in browser.

Comment: Ok but how come it is trying to make a GET request? My call in socketFactory is "io.connect('http://localhost:5555/', {'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']});". What is wrong with that?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you're trying to open the url in the browser, because you wrote "trying to go to"

Comment: I think you need to take a look at https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ You haven't mentioned you created a socket.io/1/ namespace at server side. That's why it works only for http://localhost/

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. I did NOT created any namespace on the server. Not in my knwoledge at least. I downgraded socket.io on server side now and it looks better. But im not sure its working. I dont get 400 any more at least. On server side I do (and did) this: var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);

Comment: Now I get an error in firefox: Firefox cannot estabilish connection to ws://localhost/socket.io/1/websocket/1147323759171387168.

Comment: And this is what happens on server side: debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/1147323759171387168
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 1147323759171387168
   warn  - websocket connection invalid
   info  - transport end
   debug - set close timeout for client 1147323759171387168
   debug - cleared close timeout for client 1147323759171387168
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 1147323759171387168
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 1246931271698583094